# Cucumber test results with CucumberException: Failed to instantiate public

Tags: junit, cucumber

I am getting this error:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate public
cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader)
with [cucumber.runtime.io.MultiLoader@7006c658]     at
cucumber.runtime.Reflections.newInstance(Reflections.java:44)   at
cucumber.runtime.Reflections.instantiateSubclasses(Reflections.java:30)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.loadBackends(Runtime.java:98)   at
cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:65)    at
cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:78)     at
cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:58)    at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
Source)     at
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
Source)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at
org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104) at
org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at
org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at
org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
```

Below are the jars I have in my build path:

```
cucumber core 1.2.4  
cucumber java 1.1.3  
cucumber junit 1.2.4 
cucumber jvm deps 1.0.5  
cucumber html 0.2.2  
cucumber reporting 2.2.0
gherkin 2.12.2  
selenium java 2.53.0  
selenium server  
standalone > 2.53.1
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like some dependencies mismatch. Generally, you need these to run Cucumber in Java:

- `cucmber-junit`
- `cucumber-java`
- `junit`

I see that you already have `cucumber-html` in your list. Try to remove it and see if that helps. Also, make sure you don't have other unneeded dependencies that can be removed.

Comment: If i remove that and run i get this error

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Formatter
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)